# Can I allow inline images in markdown files when using remark-rehype?

Tags: javascript, html, markdown

We server markdown files as documentation for using our SDK and one of our websites uses remark and rehype to process and display them inline in the browser as html:

```
const processor = unified()
  .use(remarkParse)
  .use(remarkRehype, {
    allowDangerousHtml: true,
  })
  .use(rehypeHighlight, {
    ignoreMissing: true,
    languages: {
      gradle,
      java,
      kotlin,
      xml,
    },
    subset: ["kotlin", "java", "gradle", "xml"],
  })
  .use(rehypeReact, {
    createElement: React.createElement,
  });
```

The markdown documentation contains some inlined images that need to be displayed in the html:

```
##Consent Notice

The below consent notice should be shown to:

* All new users of your app
* All existing and returning users who have not seen the consent request before

<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAA2ADYAAD...==" width="300">
```

(We don't have a convenient place to put hostable images so this is our temporary solution.)

When I render the HTML from remarkRehype, it has stripped the image out of the rendered html. Is there a way to allow it to persist through the conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. It turns out you need to use [rehype-raw](https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype-raw) to maintain HTML inside the markdown during transformation. Otherwise the HTML is removed, which was what happened to my missing images.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `rehype-sanitize` with the following config:

```
{
  ...defaultSchema,
  protocols: {
    src: [...(defaultSchema.protocols?.src ?? []), 'data'],
  },
},
```

using `{ defaultSchema } from 'hast-util-sanitize'`